# How do I get the number of rows from a table and insert into the same table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, I would like to write a MySql query to achieve the result below:

```
Id | C1 | C2 | Score | Q | CCount | RF |  
1    | A  | B  | 0.25 | 40 |   4   |      
2    | A  | B  | 0.60 | 40 |   4   |      
3    | A  | C  | 0.10 | 20 |   2   |      
4    | A  | B  | 0.90 | 40 |   4   |      
5    | A  | C  | 0.30 | 20 |   2   |      
6    | A  | B  | 0.70 | 40 |   4   |
```

The CCount column is the total number of rows per combination ie AB, AC etc..
In the table the above ABs have a total count of 4 rows while the ACs have a total count of 2 rows.

1. Should I use 2 tables? The Main table and a count table and then, insert count result back into the main table using group by etc.. If so, how would I go about it?
2. Is there another way of solving my problem?

This part below, I can do:

I am doing this because I would like to calculate RF (Relative Frequency) of each row.

`RF = Score * Q/CCount`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you are doing this wrong (as I cant see the whole problem).

Just tested this now, you can do this in query.

```
select count(CONCAT(C1,C2)) as count, CONCAT(C1,C2) as name from data group by C1,C2
```

output is

```
count combo
4   AB
2   AC
```

From here you should be able to get the RF as I have got the totals.
To make things simple you can now do a 2nd query running through the rows and calculating the score.

Its possible that you could do a subquery. But that is getting really tricky.

John.

Comment: Thanks John.. Yes I can see that there's going to be alot more coding in that and like you mentioned.. tricky as well..